# Is every independent subset $S$ of a vector subspace $W$ such that $\operatorname{card}(S)=\dim(W)$ a basis for $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I was reading a theorem that states that if $W$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space then every independent subset $S \subset W$  can be extended to form a basis of $W$ by repeatedly adding vectors in  way such that the resulting set continues to be linearly independent. But, can´t it be the case that we arrive by that process to a independent subset $S^*\subset W$ with $\operatorname{card}(S^*)=\dim(W)$ that is not a basis of W?
I suspect that the answer is no, in that case,I would be grateful if you  gave me some hints so I could write a proof

Comment: Hint: First prove that each basis in $W$ consists of exactly $n$ vectors, where $n=\mbox{dim}(W)$. Thus every linearly independent subset of $n$ vectors forms a basis in $W$.

Comment: It might be useful to think of the sequence of extensions, $S = S_0 \subsetneq S_1 \subsetneq S_2 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq S^*$, and their corresponding un-spanned subspaces, $W / \langle S_0 \rangle \supsetneq W / \langle S_1 \rangle \supsetneq \cdots \supsetneq W / \langle S^* \rangle$.